# Can someone explain how to use fmdb's FMDatabaseQueue?

Tags: iphone, fmdb

I saw that FMDatabaseQueue is a new addition to fmdb to help handle background thread db calls. It seems like it's just what I need, but I can't find any documentation explaining how to make and handle query/update requests.

Does anybody have any experience with it? Can you post some sample code or an explanation?

Thanks

Branch: github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tree/threadtests

The classes are there, I just don't see how to use the queue.

Comment: Not seeing what you are referring to: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb Never mind, found the branch: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/tree/threadtests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking around for the same thing and up until today I wasn't able to find much. Gus updated the github repo today with fmdb 2.0, and it has in depth documentation on how to use the FMDatabaseQueue.

Here is the [Link](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)